# Binding kendo grid to local data, It ajax "http://localhost", how to solve?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Binding kendo grid to local data, It ajax current page("http://localhost"), how to solve?
When the page load, the current page("http://localhost") get 2 times.

**My View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.RecordModel>()
    .Name("ResultGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductTitle).Width(250).Title("Title").HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "GridTextLeft"});
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductCode).Width(110).Title("Code").HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "GridTextLeft"});
    })
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(380))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .PageSize(10)    
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
            model.Field(p => p.ProductTitle);
            model.Field(p => p.ProductCode);    
        })
    )

    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pager => pager
        .ButtonCount(1)
        .PreviousNext(true)
        .Messages(t => t.Display("{2} item"))
    )
)
```

Comment: you are binding kendo grid with local data but I can't find that code.

Comment: @JayeshGoyani  Yes, I am want to binding the local data, but it ajax "http://localhost", I want to remove the ajax operation.

Answer (score 1):

It needs that Kendo Grid to be pointed to your controller method that returns data if it is Ajax binding:

```
...
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")) //Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format.
       )
)
...
```

Check the manual at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding .

UPDATE. If you require server binding then apply the `BindTo` method as per http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/server-binding

Comment: I do not need the kendo grid to get data using ajax.

Comment: Remove call to `...Ajax()` then?

Comment: If i remove the Ajax(), it reported compilation errors.

Comment: Have you tried the server binding? See the update in the answer. Hope it helps! Please don't forget to vote the answer

Comment: Please see http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding,

Comment: Although not solve the problem, I still vote your answer. @Artyom